# Ubuntu Focal 20.04 update with kept back files

Tags: updates

Today (02 September) I have proposed updates but few of them are kept back:

```
base-files/focal-updates 11ubuntu5.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 11ubuntu5.1]
ubuntu-server/focal-updates 1.450.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.450.1]
```

Why are they not update ?

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

install them manually

```
sudo apt-get install base-files sosreport
```

> http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 ubuntu-server amd64 1.450.2
> http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 base-files amd64 11ubuntu5.2

Comment: What are we supposed to do with the last two lines in your answer?